Name of the perspector of the orthic triangle and excentral triangle
The orthic triangle and tangential triangles of a given triangle are in perspective. What's the official kimberling center associated with this perspector?


The way to answer questions like this is to calculate the barycentrics for the triangle with side lengths 6, 9, 13 and look them up in https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/Search_6_9_13.html
